# sed substitution with a variable

Tags: sed, variable

I am trying to remove the first n characters from a string
I get the following error :

```
line 5: ${ echo $data | sed -r 's/.{ $index0 }//' }: bad substitution
```

when using this code from within a bash script :

```
data=${ echo $data | sed -r 's/.{$index}//' }
```

any correction please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well,

1. Command substitution is `$( ... )`, not `${ ... }`. Regular parenthesis, not curly braces.
2. You have `$index` within single-quotes, so it will *not* be expanded by the shell. You need double-quotes for that.
3. Put double-quotes around `$data` in the echo, it makes a difference if `data` contains whitespace or glob characters
4. In bash, you can just use  the substring expansion `data=${data:$index}` to drop a number of characters from the front of the string.

Suggested reading: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide